# Retrieving AD username without domain

Tags: c#, authentication, active-directory, windows-authentication, iprincipal

I am currently switching an old c# intranet application which used Forms authentication and Profiles (SQL) to authenticate and keep track of users. However, now I am converting it to work with Windows authentication.

I have got most of it working but the issue now is that I have to handle the new username schema. For example, previously, usernames were saved like so for a John Doe: `jdoe`. Now, since I am using windows authentication, I receive the username as `EXAMPLE\\jdoe` (where `EXAMPLE` is the domain name).

I understand that I can simply split the received username to just get `jdoe` -- and I had been doing that for testing purposes -- but that solution is only feasible where I am working only with strings. There are instances where I need to work directly with the `User` object (`System.Security.Principal.IPrincipal.Page.User`) like in case I need to use the `User.IsInRole()` method which is only accessible to `User` objects and not strings.

Now my question is, **can I set this is up in some way that by default** `User.Identity.Name` **returns** `jdoe` **instead of** `EXAMPLE\\jdoe` **while still using Windows authentication?**

One bruteforce solution would be to recreate every user with the domain prepended and handle the domain and username split in edge cases. But I'd rather not go that route unless absolutely necessary.

Comment: @Am_I_Helpful well I did include the desired result. I asked if there was a way that I could have System.Security.Principal.IPrincipal.Page.User.Name to always return the name **without** the domain. Like `jdoe` instead of `EXAMPLE\\jdoe`. I can provide more information but what else is unclear?

Comment: Did you try `User.Identity.Name` to see if it gets the name of the current user? What does it return?

Comment: My apologies, `User.Name` doesn't exist. I already am calling `User.Identity.Name` and it does return `EXAMPLE\jdoe`. I forgot to include the Identity part when writing the post.

Comment: IMO, you're using the correct approach `except use Substring() method instead of split()`, because for user groups, Microsoft uses the default naming convention `BUILTIN\Administrators` prepending a default domain like pattern to identify the type of account. Your approach looks logical to me.